# Add noise to dashed spiral plot

Tags: matlab, image-processing, spiral

How can I add noise in this matlab spiral plot ??

```
 t = linspace(0,6*pi,1000);
 x = t.*cos(t);
 y = t.*sin(t);
 h = plot(x,y);
 set(h(1),'linewidth',20);
 set(h(1),'LineStyle','--');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
k = 0.2;
x = t.*cos(t) + k*(rand(size(t))-0.5);
y = t.*sin(t) + k*(rand(size(t))-0.5);
```

fiddle with `k` to adjust the amplitude of your noise.

Comment: rather `k*rand(size(t))-k/2`?